# Could you tell me what the difference between these words is?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

I have three sentences as below.

1. At present, the **numbers** of confirmed cases are very high.
2. At present, the **volume** of the confirmed cases is very high.
3. At preset, the **quantity** of the confirmed cases is very high.

Could you tell me the three bold words are used correctly? I mean I’d like to know what the difference among them is, and how to use the words correctly. Because they look very similar in context, often confusing me.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't imagine any possible difference in *meaning*. But by far the most ***common*** word here would be (singular) *the **number** of confirmed cases **is** very high.* But it doesn't really make much sense with ***at present***, since the number of comfirmed cases right now is actually still extremely ***low*** compared to what we expect to see in the next few weeks / months. Do you perhaps mean ***already*** rather than ***at present***? Also note that you don't want ***the*** before ***confirmed cases***.

Comment: With _quantity_, I would use _large_ rather than _high_. It's more appropriate when measuring something non-countable than when speaking of numbers.